# Make function pointers members of structures in c

Tags: c, gdb, valgrind

I am completely noob when I work with C. Very weak with pointers.

I have written a struct for a binary search tree. But when I try to access it from code it throws an error:

> Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV).
>   Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x0`.

Here is my struct (in `bst.h`):

```
typedef struct tree Tree;

typedef struct tree{
    Node * root;
    Data * (*insert)(Tree * bst, Data value); //i get error in main when I make a call
    Data * (*search)(Tree * bst, Data value);
    void (*sort)(Tree *, Data *);
    int (*compare)(Tree *t, Tree * copy);
    Tree * (*clone)(Tree *t);
    void  (*delete)(Tree *bst);
    void  (*removeData)(Tree * bst, Data value);
}Tree;
```

Member functions (in `bst.c`):

```
Node * newNode(Data data, Node * parent) {
    printf("inside new node\n");
    Node * node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(parent!=NULL) {
        if((parent->data.value)> data.value) {
            parent->left=node;
        }
        else {
            parent->right=node;
        }
    }
    node->parent=parent;
    node->left=NULL;
    node->right=NULL;
    node->data=data;
    printf("after inside newNode\n");
    return node;
}

Tree * newTree() {
    Tree *tree;
    tree = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    tree->root=NULL;
    return tree;
}

// not getting inside in this function
Data * insert(Tree * tree, Data data) {
    if(tree->root==NULL) {
        tree->root = newNode(data,NULL);
    } else{
        return insertNode(tree->root,data);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Here is my `main()` that calls this function (in `main.c`):

```
Tree *bst = newTree();
assert(bst->root == NULL);

printf("1.");
for (i = 0; i < num_data; i++){
    bst->insert(bst, (Data){d[i]});
    printf("inside for loop");
}
```

I am not sure whether this is the right way to make function pointers as members of struct.

Comment: It's not clear what you want exactly because there's no actual question in there. Your code has a bug, most likely a NULL pointer dereference. Can you give us enough code to replicate the bug? Also, why is this tagged C++?

Comment: I recommend removing the C++ tag, since your title says you are programming in C and your questions states you are programming in C.  They are different langyages.  For example, `struct tree` defines `tree` as a type in C++.

Comment: Where do you initialize all the function pointers?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews added more code

Comment: Your structure has pointers to functions.  Where do you initialize these pointers?  You call `newTree()`, but the structure members, like `insert` are not initialized.  You should make the `insert` pointer point to a valid function.

Comment: This is pretty advanced stuff for a complete noob.

Comment: @Barmar true. I did not write the code. I was playing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `newTree()`, you are not assigning your functions to the function-pointers inside of the allocated `tree` struct.

```
Data* insert(Tree* tree, Data data);
// other function declarations as needed...

Tree* newTree() {
    Tree *tree = (Tree*) malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    if (!tree) return NULL;

    tree->root = NULL;

    tree->insert = &insert; // <-- ADD THIS!
    // and do the same for your other function pointers...
    tree->search = ...;
    tree->sort = ...;
    tree->compare = ...;
    tree->clone = ...;
    tree->delete = ...;
    tree->removeData = ...;

    return tree;
}
```

Comment: It says functions are undeclared.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. By looking at it looks easy. I would not have come up with the solution on my own.

Comment: You have to make sure the functions are *declared* before the implementation of `newTree()` so it can get their addresses.